# Rasterizing a large image with Rasterio

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, rasterize

I am rasterizing polygons in a large raster using the following code:

```
import rasterio.features
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p1 = Polygon([[0,0], [32000,0], [32000,32000], [0,0]])
out_shape = (32000, 32000)
# The default transform is fine here
r = rasterio.features.rasterize([p1], out_shape=out_shape)
```

This operation works fine if the Raster is smaller. For out_shape of (10000, 10000), it takes a couple of seconds but works fine. However, it fails for the given shape of (32000, 32000).

I looked into the code for [rasterio.features.rasterize](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/main/rasterio/_features.pyx) and it mentions that

> If GDAL max cache size is smaller than the output data, the array of shapes will be iterated multiple times. Performance is thus a linear function of buffer size. For maximum speed, ensure that GDAL_CACHEMAX is larger than the size of out or out_shape.

I increased the GDAL_CACHEMAX using

```
from osgeo import gdal
max_gdal_cache_gb=64
gdal.SetCacheMax(int(max_gdal_cache_gb * 1e9))
```

However, still rasterio is enable to rasterize the large raster. Also I am not sure if the GDAL_CACHEMAX is actually increased. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the above code worked fine but the issue was in the next step. Anyways, here is a improved version of the code, where the max cache is also printed:

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.features
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from osgeo import gdal

max_gdal_cache_gb=64

# Create a global rasterio environment
global_env = rasterio.Env(GDAL_CACHEMAX=int(max_gdal_cache_gb * 1e9))

with global_env:
    # Get the current cache size
    rasterio_cache_size = gdal.GetConfigOption("GDAL_CACHEMAX")
    print(f"Rasterio cache size: {rasterio_cache_size} bytes")


p1 = Polygon([[0,0], [32000,0], [32000,32000], [0,0]])
out_shape = (32000, 32000)
# The default transform is fine here
with global_env:
    r = rasterio.features.rasterize([p1], out_shape=out_shape)
```